# Exporting data from Excel into GAMS

Tags: export, gams-math

I want to load data from excel sheet into GAMS, each excel sheet has one column and 8760 rows (where each row has a values), and I am using the below code,

```
`Parameter PV_Available(k);
$call gdxxrw "C:\Users\omarr\OneDrive\Desktop\GAMS\Model Development\Fourth Draft (First Run)\Data\PV_Available.xlsx" par=PV_Available rng=Sheet1!A1:A8760 rdim=1 output="PV_Available.gdx"
$gdxin PV_Available.gdx
$load PV_Available
$gdxin`
```

```
`Parameter Wind_Available(k);
$call gdxxrw "C:\Users\omarr\OneDrive\Desktop\GAMS\Model Development\Fourth Draft (First Run)\Data\Wind_Available.xlsx" par=Wind_Available rng=Sheet1!A1:A8760 rdim=1 output="Wind_Available.gdx"
$gdxin Wind_Available.gdx
$load Wind_Available
$gdxin
`
```

the code is running without errors, but the created gdx files do not have the data avaialble in the excel sheets, Could someone please help me identifying where is the error?

I was trying to export data from excel sheets into GAMS, the code is running without errors, but the created gdx files do not have the data avaialble in the excel sheets, Could someone please help me identifying where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to increase the [trace](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/T_GDXXRW.html#GDXXRW_OPTIONS_TRACE) value to get more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I found the solution, https://forum.gamsworld.org/viewtopic.php?p=30811#p30811,
the problem was the set up of the excel sheet.